# How can I read undefined number of bytes from com port, using boost?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, serial-port

I'm trying to write and read data from com port. I' using

```
    write(*ioboard.port, buffer(cpayload, cpayload.size()));
```

for writing and i have some troubles with receiving answer.
I tried different variants

```
int m = read(*ioboard.port, buffer(answer, 1));
int m = read(*ioboard.port, buffer(answer, 1024));

int m = ioboard.port->read_some(buffer(answer));
```

In first case I received answer after first call of write-read pair and no answer after second: fanction read glitching. In second case I didn't receive answer after first call: again due to the read function. Third works the same way as first. So now I need reboot my devise to send it two commands!

How should I read, if I know maximum data size, but do not know how many bytes, I'll get in particular way.

Comment: `read_some` will read some of the data available in the i/o port. What's wrong with it?

Comment: It's glitching if I call read_some the second time.

Comment: How is it glitching?

Comment: It happend because nothing was in that port. I have no deep understanding of what happend, but I solved this problem for now by creating symblink to /dev/ttyACM0 and connecting to it. Don't understand why so happened - seems that only discriptor was changed.

Answer (score 0):

It happend because nothing was in that port. I have no deep understanding of what happend, but I solved this problem for now by creating symblink to /dev/ttyACM0 and connecting to it. Don't understand why so happened - seems that only discriptor was changed. – voronwe

Answer (score -1):

If you are okay with using **Qt** tool kit try doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html